Can I say: "Playing football is a healthy recreation"? Is recreation countable?
According to OD, recreation in the sense of a pastime/hobby is countable.
However, when I searched for "this recreation" or "a recreation" online, most of the examples were in the sense of "the activity of recreating something", not "a pastime".
Then, I tried to have a look at some examples in the dictionary and saw this sentence:

His only form of recreation is playing football.

Why form of recreation instead of just recreation? These occurrences made me feel like recreation can't really be used like hobby or pastime, as  a singular noun. So, can I say the following sentence?

Playing football is a healthy recreation.


There are several issues in this question.
(1) Can recreation be countable?
Yes. There are examples if you put a bit of effort in:

we promote local community participation in a healthy recreation through the provision of facilities and the promotion of table tennis. (A table tennis league)


the government [is] only interested in dance as a healthy recreation (submission to UK parliament by Freelance Dance)


It is a healthy recreation as well as being a worthwhile chore to clear up leaves which can become slippery and then dangerous. (Discussion about gardening on Internet Archive)

But it is more common to use recreation in other ways, e.g. non-countable or modifying another noun like "recreation center".
(2) Why do people say "form of recreation"?
"Form of" is used when making a generalization, when talking about things in general rather than particular instances. It can be used with non-countable nouns as well as countable, or if you're not sure if a noun is countable, or if it's not normally used as a countable noun.
If you want to explain that there are various types of recreation with different qualities, in English you commonly use a word like "form", "type", or "style". This indicates you're comparing different types of recreation (rather than individual occurrences like me playing football last Thursday). In "His only form of recreation is playing football" you are saying that while there are other types of recreation, he does no other type of recreation.
(3) You don't ask this, but it's not very common to describe football as a recreation.
Recreation normally refers to something that's relaxing and revitalising: the first definition in Merriam-Webster is "refreshment of strength and spirits after work". I guess playing sports might refresh your spirits, but it would vary from person to person.
It would be more usual to refer to football as "a sport" or "an activity". A recreation is something which lets you relax: some people may find football relaxing but they're probably in the minority. Similarly, words like "hobby" are often reserved for less active things like crafting or collecting.

As well as "form of recreation," "recreational activity" is a common collocation. I disagree that it would be at all unusual to describe a sport as recreation; the primary emphasis is "done for fun, not for work." It need not be limited to low-impact, zen-like activities but could include martial arts, roller derby, parkour or other strenuous and violent pastimes.

The main meaning of recreation is uncountable - activities you do in order to enjoy yourself. If you call a particular activity a recreation, it's really a shorter way of saying a form of recreation. I notice that the Oxford definition that you get from googling 'recreation definition' does not include the countable sense.
So - yes, you would be understood if you called football a recreation, but it's better to include form of.
(Stuart got there before me.)
